# How to iterate the speech output by alexa?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to iterate the speech output of alexa

```
for(var i = 0; i< status.passengers.length; i++) {
                    console.log("----inside getJson--------->",status.passengers[i].current_status);
                    let reservationStauts = status.passengers[i].current_status;

                    statusWords = reservationStauts.split("/");
                    for(var j=0; j < statusWords.length; j++) {
                        confirmStatus = statusWords[0];
                        statusNumber = statusWords[2];
                    }
                    passenger = status.passengers[i].no;
                    speechOutput = "the p n r status for passenger "+passenger+" is "+confirmStatus+statusNumber;
                    callback(session.attributes, buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, "", false));
                }
```

but since the callback changes the controller, i am not able to get the second iteration of the speech output.

Basically i'm trying to iterate the speech output!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really nothing unique to Alexa here, instead it's a javascript and callback processing matter.  The trick is to not call the callback until absolutely necessary.
In this case since it looks like you're trying to build a response containing information for multiple patters you'd *probably* be best served moving the callback outside the outermost for loop.

I've taken a stab at updating your snippet below:
**NOTE:** I've also moved the declaration of speechOutput outside the loop so that you can build it through each iteration of the loop

```
let speechOutput = ''; // need to declare this outside the loop and treat the loop as your speech builder
for(var i = 0; i< status.passengers.length; i++) {
    console.log("----inside getJson--------->",status.passengers[i].current_status);
    let reservationStauts = status.passengers[i].current_status;

    statusWords = reservationStauts.split("/");
    for(var j=0; j < statusWords.length; j++) {
        confirmStatus = statusWords[0];
        statusNumber = statusWords[2];
    }
    passenger = status.passengers[i].no;
    speechOutput += "the p n r status for passenger "+passenger+" is "+confirmStatus+statusNumber;
    speechOutput += ',\n'; //SINCE you're looping over multiples - should probably throw some sort of speach separator/pause here

}
callback(session.attributes, buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, "", false));
```